# json_decode emoji gives strange characters like: ðY''

Tags: php, emoji

I am receiving messages from Facebook Messenger to my PHP server.

I `json_decode` the request like this:

```
$facebookRequest = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input'), true );
```

After that, the emojis in the text all come out as these strange characters, and not as Hex or Unicode formats.

The characters don't even post correctly here so here is a screenshot of them:
[image: strange characters] that's from a simple smiley face.

Now I can reverse the text through `json_encode` then I get: `\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0080`.

Is there a better way to handle emojis passing through `json_decode`?

Comment: try `utf8_decode`

Comment: When you do `json_encode` again you seem to be getting the correct character back. Maybe it's your output encoding that's messing what you see up

Answer (score 0):

Try rawurlencode or decode methods before passing to json_ decode.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php