# How can I parse character codes from a Facebook Messenger data dump into characters / emojis?

Tags: facebook, emoji, messenger

I have downloaded a data dump of my entire Facebook Messenger history in JSON format. I am trying to render messages in a basic PHP application but emojis and certain other characters are coming out like this:

```
I didnât get checked for id !!!
```

This is the corresponding JSON data:

```
"content": "I didn\u00e2\u0080\u0099t get checked for id !!!"
```

I have tried [rawurldecode and utf8_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798486/json-decode-emoji-gives-strange-characters-like-%c3%b0y), [decodeURI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465642/how-to-display-an-emoji-in-a-facebook-messenger-bot) and even [a more complicated regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha), but the characters keep rendering the same. I have also attempted to set UTF8 explicitly using PHP headers, but again no luck.

Here is my basic code:

```php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('message_1.json'));

$messages = $json->messages;

$messages = array_reverse($messages);

foreach($messages as $m) {

    if(!isset($m->content)) continue;

    $ts = $m->timestamp_ms;
    $date = date('d/m/Y', $ts / 1000);

    echo "<strong>{$m->sender_name} ($date):</strong> $content<br>";
}
```

There are no errors and the messages render fine, except with any "\uXXX" characters being rendered incorrectly.

When parsing the following data:

```
"content": "I don\u00e2\u0080\u0099t have the key"
```

I would expect to see:

```
I don't have the key
```

However, my browser (Chrome) renders:

```
I donât have the key
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give!